# A problem with overriding OnPaint when DoubleBuffered set to true

Tags: c#, winforms, doublebuffered, onpaint

I have created a custom control which derives from Panel. I use it to display an Image using BackgroundImage property. I override the OnClick method and set isSelected to true then call Invalidate method and draw a rectangle in overrided OnPaint.
Everything goes just fine until I set DoubleBuffered to true. The rectangle is drawn and then it is erased and I can't get why this is happening.

```
public CustomControl()
    : base()
{
    base.DoubleBuffered = true;

    base.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
{
    base.OnPaint(pe);

    PaintSelection();
}

private void PaintSelection()
{
    if (isSelected)
    {
        Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics();
        graphics.DrawRectangle(SelectionPen, DisplayRectangle.Left, DisplayRectangle.Top, DisplayRectangle.Width - 1, DisplayRectangle.Height - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `PaintSelection`, you should not create a new `Graphics` object, because that object will draw to the front buffer, which is then promptly overdrawn by the contents of the back buffer.

Paint to the `Graphics` passed in the `PaintEventArgs` instead:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
{
    base.OnPaint(pe);
    PaintSelection(pe.Graphics);
}

private void PaintSelection(Graphics graphics)
{
    if (isSelected)
    {
        graphics.DrawRectangle(SelectionPen, DisplayRectangle.Left, DisplayRectangle.Top, DisplayRectangle.Width - 1, DisplayRectangle.Height - 1);
    }
}
```