# Windows Forms Bitmap vs. Drawing Speed

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, bitmap, drawing

I have data in a multidimensional array of doubles and I want to draw it on my form in a grid (with different values being different colors). Write now I am using a `Panel` control and in its `OnPaint()` I do do the drawing by calling `Graphics.DrawRectangle()` for each entry in the array. The data changes very frequently, so I call `Refresh()` on the panel when it does, but this is quite slow and I get a lot of flickering, I can also see the drawing of each rectangle happen sequentially, and I know that parallel drawing of the rectangles is not possible, because it is not thread-safe.

Would constructing a `Bitmap` where each pixel is an entry in the array, and then setting a `PictureBox` to show the `Bitmap` (and scale its size up) be faster than using the panel and `OnPaint`?

Here is a sample of the code I am using:

```
namespace PredPreySim
    {
    public partial class SimulationForm : Form
    {
        Simulation simulation; // instance of the simulation class
        bool running = true;
        int simWidth = 30;
        int simHeight = 20;
        int cellSize = 15;

        System.Threading.Thread t;

        public SimulationForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            simulation = new Simulation(simWidth, simHeight, numHerbivores, 0.3);
            graphicsTimeDelay = Convert.ToInt32(GraphicsTimeDelay.Value);
            ResizePanel();
        }

        private void ResizePanel()
        {
            panel1.Width = simWidth * cellSize;
            panel1.Height = simHeight * cellSize;
        }


        // draws the board
        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
            RectangleF rectangle = new Rectangle();
            rectangle.Width = cellSize;
            rectangle.Height = cellSize;

            // draw all the plants
            Color plantColor;
            for (int i = 0; i < simWidth; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < simHeight; ++j)
                {
                    int r, g = 255, b;
                    r = b = 255 - (int)(255.0 * Math.Tanh(simulation.plants[i, j]));
                    plantColor = Color.FromArgb(100, r, g, b);
                    brush.Color = plantColor;
                    rectangle.Location = new PointF(i * cellSize, j * cellSize);
                    graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rectangle);
                }
            }

            brush.Dispose();
            graphics.Dispose();
        }

        private void StartStopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (running) // then stop
            {
                running = false;
                StartStopButton.Text = "Start";
            }
            else // start
            {
                running = true;
                StartStopButton.Text = "Stop";
                t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.runSimulation));
                t.Start();
                t.Priority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.Highest;
            }
        }

        private void runSimulation()
        {
            while (running)
            {
                simulation.Update();
                panel1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(Refresh)); // makes the call thread-safe   
            }
            t.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you enable DoubleBuffered? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255368/a-problem-with-overriding-onpaint-when-doublebuffered-set-to-true  You might want to share a small [MCVE] how you handle the onpaint and call refresh. Using a picturebox seems logical.

Comment: DoubleBuffered is not enabled... should it be?

Comment: Yes it should. To do so you need to subclass Panel or switch to a PictureBox, which is DoubleBuffered by default. Also: Instead of Refresh do call Invalidate! - As for using a Bitmap: It really depends on the number and scope of the changes..

Comment: You should let the data change as frequent as it can be but leave the rendering to a dedicate controller, who picks up the current data before rendering and renders the UI at a constant frequency (30Hz for instance). That's because human eyes cannot observe high frequency changes, and if you data change more frequently you waste resources to always render them.

Comment: I tried enabling DoubleBuffer with `typeof(Panel).InvokeMember("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.SetProperty    
            | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null,
            panel2, new object[] { true });` but it really didn't make a difference

Comment: Also, I am pretty sure that I want `Refresh()` not `Invalidate()` and `Update()` because I want the changes to happen right away

Comment: Spawning a thread that does nothing but marshals a call across to the UI thread repeatedly is a waste.  Better to simply use a fixed UI timer of say 30Hz that calls `Invalidate()`.

Comment: No, no  and no. Invalidate is what you want, neither Refresh nor Update. And inserting DoubleBuffer via Reflection is weird and not how either was meant.. And only dispose of things you create: You didn't create the Graphics (,thank god!) And instead of Disposing get used to `using`. And for animation on the UI thread use a Timer! - Finally consider caching the TanH values.

Comment: Bitmap and pictureBox did the trick.